# How to set color of all DONE type TODO's

Tags: org-mode, colors

If I eg define the following in an .org file:

> #+TODO: TODO(t) ACTIVE(v) NEXT(x) WAITING(w) PROCESS(p) CONSIDER(c) USE(u) GOOD(g) ISSUE(i) CURRENT(4) ONHOLD(h) LATER(l) SOMEDAY(8) | DONE(d) ABANDONED(a) OLD(o) REFERENCE(f)

Then org mode, by default, colors all TODO types above (the ones on the left of the "|" ) as pink , and org mode colors all DONE types (the ones on the right of the "|" ) as green.

I would like to change the color of ALL DONE types.

I did find out how to color specific TODO keywords, eg:

> (setq org-todo-keyword-faces
> '(("WAITING" . "magenta") ("CANCELED" . "red") ("DONE" . "green"))
> )

But this is not a great solution for me since I often change the names of TODO and DONE type keywords, and have different ones for different files.

I have searched to try to find a way to set the color of ALL DONE types but have not found anything.

Since org mode has a default color for all DONE types, I am hoping I can change this default color.

Is there a way to set the color of ALL DONE types?

Comment: See the variable `org-todo-keywords-1` and the variable `org-done-keywords`, both of which are lists of strings and the fall-back/default *faces* are `org-todo` and `org-done`.  Org-mode would need to know which words represent done and todo, so it can colorize them.  Faces can be customized with `M-x customize-face` as well as by being set directly in the user init file.

Comment: lawlist thanks very much for taking the time to respond :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions like this can be answered using `describe-char` (which you can also execute with `C-u C-x =`) while your cursor is on the relevant character (any of the characters in the keyword will do). If you do that on different `DONE` keywords on a headline (i.e. do `C-c C-t` repeatedly on a headline in order to cycle through all the possible `TODO` keywords, then do `C-u C-x =` on some character of each of the `DONE` keywords in the cycle), you will see that each one of them has an `org-done` face.

Now do `M-x describe-face RET org-done` to see the properties of the face. In my case, I get `PaleGreen` as the foreground color. To change it you say:

```el
(set-face-foreground 'org-done "Red")
```

Check that the color has changed.

To change it permanently, you have to do that but you have to make sure that the face is defined already. The `org-done` face is defined in the file `org-faces.el` (`describe-face` gives you that information too). So
add this to your init file:

```el
(eval-after-load 'org-faces
    (set-face-foreground 'org-done "Red"))
```

to change it permanently. This will execute the `set-face-foreground` command only *after* the `org-faces` file is loaded, so that the `org-done` face will have been defined and you will be able to modify it.

Also make sure that you spell the color correctly, otherwise you might get some default color. Do `M-x list-color-display` to see the list of available colors and how to spell them.

Comment: NickD thanks again for your once again great help :) - it works like a charm!